# AWS AppSync resolver cache

Tags: caching, aws-appsync

We want to enable cache only for a specific graphql query. I created the cache and chose "per-resolver caching" in appsync console. Then I enabled cache inside the query resolver. However, the caching metric shows no cache hits or misses. It seems the query was not cached at all and the request still went to the data source as indicated from backend logging.

Enabling full-request caching from console works fine for all queries. Has anyone seen the similar issues? Do I need to explicitly set the cachingConfig for the resolver? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved. It turns out that I need to save the updated cache config...

Comment: Are you using amplify? I'm facing an issue when I make a new deploy, the cache config are reset and I have to enabled it again on the query.